# How can I turn silent mode on (Lenovo yoga 2)

Tags: lenovo

I just got Lenovo yoga 2 and can not find silent mode (power button offers just - power of, resrt and aeroplane mode). There must be silnt mode to turn every sound off...
Big thanks!

Comment: Can'y You find the option to toggle User profile such as Silent/Normal/Outdoor Mode in **"Settings"** App of Lenovo Yoga 2 Device?

Answer (score 0):

Most phones go in silent mode when you just press volume down and silence it to the end. After hitting lowest volume, pressing it again should put it in vibrate only mode, and pressing it again will put it in silent mode. I'm not sure if Lenovo phones have that implemented but most other OEMs have it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

In my Lenovo K3 Note there's a "Do Not Disturb" function. You can activate it from a button in the notification toolbar, the one that pictures a moon.